# Issue doing reverse proxy using apache with subdomain

Tags: apache, sinatra, reverse-proxy

I am trying to do a mod_proxy implementation of a sintra application using a subdirectory uri on the proxy host.  Here is my apache proxy config area:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /api/ http://127.0.0.1:9292/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://127.0.0.1:9292/
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

The problem I am running into, is that the links within the sinatra rendered page are not resulting in the /api prefix on the links... For example, when I do `to('/some_page')` within an erb template, it gives me

> http://www.externalhost.com/some_page

instead of

> http://www.externalhost.com/api/some_page

Does anyone know how to properly do this where the subdirectory will be honored in generating the url?  To run the backend server, I'm simply using the default as: rackup config.ru where my config is:

```
require 'rubygems'
load File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app.rb')
run App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /api/ http://127.0.0.1:9292/api/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://127.0.0.1:9292/api/
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

Comment: I was trying to do this without having to have /api/ on the destination, but doing so worked correctly.  Thanks!